# WSO2 ESB Call SOAP Endpoint couldn't perform operation

Tags: soap, wsdl, call, endpoint, wso2-esb

I want to call SOAP endpoint URL with Action from WSO2 ESB. I could call the SOAP URL and getting entire wsdl response but i couldn't perform the Action.

Let say my wsdl respone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions ....>
 <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema  ..>...</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:service>..</wsdl:service>

 <wsdl:portType name="..">

<wsdl:operation name="AAA">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:in"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:out"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="fault1" message="tns:Error"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="BBB">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:in"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:out"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="fault1" message="tns:Error"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="CCC">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:in"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:out"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="fault1" message="tns:Error"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
......
......
</wsdl:portType>
...
```

This is my WSO2 ESB code to call SOAP Endpoint

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
          <soapenv:Envelope
            xmlns:app="...xsd"
            xmlns:com=".....xsd"
            xmlns:ser="...xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
              <ser:...Request>
                <app:ApplicationHeader>
                  <app:...>$1</app:...>
                  <app:...>$2</app:...>

                </app:ApplicationHeader>
                <ser:DataHeader>
                  <ser:....>$3</ser:...
                  <ser:...>$4</ser:...>

                </ser:DataHeader>
              </ser:...Request>
            </soapenv:Body>
          </soapenv:Envelope>
        </format>
        <args>
          <arg value="1"/>
          <arg value="2"/>
          <arg value="3"/>
          <arg value="4"/>

        </args>
      </payloadFactory>
      <header name="Action" scope="default" value="AAA"/>

      <call blocking="true">
        <endpoint>
          <address uri="http:/URL/>
        </endpoint>
      </call>
      <respond/>
```

When I call this code, i will get above entire WSDL response instead of operation "AAA"

But I should get this operation

Comment: Also getting ERROR_MESSAGE : First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found definitions

Comment: Try setting the address endpoint format to be soap11. `<address format="soap11" uri="http://URL"/>`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you specified wsdl url as an address of endpoint. That's why you receive wsdl file and an error that instead of Soap envelope it gets definitions.

You should use wsdl endpoint.

```
    <endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Service">
   <wsdl uri="https://yourServer/yourService?wsdl" service="yourService" port="yourServiceSoap">
      <suspendOnFailure>
         <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
         <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>
   </wsdl>
</endpoint>
```

Or you may use address endpoint, but take the URI from wsdl file in wsdl:port section,
for this example, take **https://yourServer/service/yourService.asmx** as an URI:

```
<service name="yourService">
<port name="yourServiceSoap" binding="yourServiceSoapBinding">    
<soapbind:address location="https://yourServer/service/yourService.asmx"/>
</port>
</service>
```